# Different styles of formatted text on one label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

is it possible to use different styles of formatted text on *one* label? For now, my label looks like this:

```
note_text = "Please note: Lorem ipsum dolor. For more information please visit www.myobscurewebsite.com"
note = Label(sub_frame, text=note_text, background="light grey", wraplength=430, justify=LEFT, width=62, height=0,
             font=("arial", 10, "italic"))
note.grid(column=0, columnspan=3, row=4, padx=5, pady=(5, 5))
```

The standard formatting for all the text is Italic, but some parts need additional formatting. 'Please note:' should be bold, the link at the end should be a hyperlink and the text in between (the 'lorem ipsum' placeholder) shouldn't have any additional text attributes. One possible way to solve this problem is to arrange different labels, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: The absolute, ultimate limit to styling a Label is that you can underline a single character.  You're going to need to use a Text, instead.

Comment: Recommend using a text widget, which allows fonts to be applied character by character. Technically a label supports exactly one font for the entire string contents being displayed. So the entire string can be bold, italics, underlined, styled with a certain color, but all characters receive the same treatment. The exception is noted by @Jasonharper above.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to use the text widget. Thanks guys.